# Is there a way to have posts at the root with Vuepress Blog plugin?

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

#### Using the Vuepress Blog plugin for a Vuepress blog website, is there a way to have posts at the root of the website?

E.g. I have `foo.com` with a post named `post-1`. I can show a PostIndex at `foo.com/` but when I click on a post it goes to `foo.com/posts/post-1`. What I want is for a post to be at `foo.com/post-1`

I tried moving my posts out of the `/posts` folder into the project root and in the following config.js

```
plugins: [
 [
  '@vuepress/blog',
  {
    directories: [
      {
        id: 'post',
        // dirname: 'posts',
        dirname: '/',
        path: '/',
        // Avoid dates in URLs
        itemPermalink: '/:regular'
      }
    ]
  }
 ]
]
```

I tried to change `directories[0].dirname` to `/`. This results in a "Page Not Found".

I know I can have `post-1` at the root in Vuepress without the Blog plugin, but I'm trying to use the Blog plugin's pagination and other features.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having this issue, it seems to be that the `directories[0].itemPermalink: '/:regular'` makes the permalink not work. Changing to `directories[0].itemPermalink: '/:slug'` solves the issue.

Internally, Vuepress Blog plugin must be checking for the string "slug".